# find example from some regularities. euclids elements

Tags: euclidean-geometry, examples-counterexamples, regularization

I heared that there are 6 basic math abilities.

and one of them is to find an example from regularities.

I want to develop this ability so I tried to find an example from real world.

but I am not sure am I correct or not.

the example what I found is moving a human to the moon.

and the regularities what I worked on was moving segment to specific point with only unmarked ruler and compass.

this is comes from Euclid`s Elements book 1, proposition 2.

you can find it from

http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI2.html

the example what I found is:

1. there is a person (can`t go to the moon on foot)
2. the person get on a rocket
3. rocket go to the moon
4. the person will be unloaded from the rocket
5. the person on the earth is moved to the moon
6. and the person stay still.

is it correct example?

the original proposition goes like this:

1. there is a segment
2. add same length to the segment
3. rotate it
4. subtract same length from the segment
5. segment is moved
6. and the both segment, before moving, after moving, are same.

thanks for reading.